# Open a file (named pipe) on a distant directory with python, ssh and os.open

Tags: python, ssh, pipe, python-os

For a project I need to open a file (in fact a named pipe) with os.open().
Here is the situation:
I have a process that creates two names pipe on a first machine (lets call them **pipeCS** and **pipeSC**). Each pipe goes in one direction (pipeCS = client->server and pipeSC = server->client).
Then we have a fork() and the first subprocess is replaced by a ssh process (with `os.execvp("ssh -e none -l [uname] [adress] [file]", [args]`)

On the **client side**, I open the two pipes with:

```
pcs_c = os.open("pipeCS", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREAT) #pipe client->server
psc_c = os.open("pipeSC", os.O_RDONLY|os.O_CREAT) #pipe server->client
```

And on the **server side**, I also want to open theses pipes with something like:

```
pcs_s = os.open("pipeCS", os.O_RDONLY|os.O_CREAT) #pipe client->server
psc_s = os.open("pipeSC", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREAT) #pipe server->client
```

It's really important to open them with **os.open()**, because I need the I/O of the pipes to be blocking and to be able to use (`os.write(fd, [data])`). Could you tell me how to open the named pipes (which are on the client side) on the server side ?

Here is my code if you want to see the context :

```
elif dic['ssh']: #client side of the code

    os.mkfifo("pipeCS") #client -> server
    os.mkfifo("pipeSC") #server -> client
    pcs_c = os.open("pipeCS", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREAT) #pipe client->server clientSide, write
    psc_c = os.open("pipeSC", os.O_RDONLY|os.O_CREAT) #pipe server->client clientSide, read

    pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            #code sender
            sender.send_local(src, dic, pcs_c, psc_c)
        else:
            #replace the client subprocess with the server process
            os.execvp("ssh -e none -l distant localhost -- ./[file] --server", [])

elif dic['--server']: #server side of the code

    pcs_s = os.open("[something to open [user]@[machine]:pipeCS]", os.O_RDONLY|os.O_CREAT) #pipe client->server
    psc_s = os.open("[something to open [user]@[machine]:pipeSC]", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREAT) #pipe server->client

    server.server_ssh(dic, pcs_s, psc_s)
```

Thank you for your attention ;)

Comment: As you mention `ssh`, a pipe cannot be used to communicate between machines (unless, perhaps, you are using some sort of SSH-mounted file system). You need to use sockets for communication over the network.

Comment: What does "distant" mean, in the phrase "a distant directory"?

Comment: It means a directory (in this case, a directory in the `home` of the user) of another user on the same computer or a user on another computer of the same network. (like `[user]@localhost` or `[user]@[local-ip]` if we are refering to the ssh command) @joseph